# Cannot receive broadcast in ICS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I writing 1 app for Android 4.0, and it's started  via broadcastreceiver. My code is below:

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="com.Android.Exercise.StartUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <!--<action android:name="StartInstrument" /> 
                <action android:name="PrintControlName" />      -->     
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>         
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="StartAUT_Service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Android.Exercise.StartAUT_Service" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>  
    </application>
```

In StartUpReceiver class:

```
public class StartUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Broadcast", "onReceive");

        Intent i = null;

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
             i = new Intent(context, StartAUT_Service.class);          
             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }

        context.startService(i);            
    }       
}
```

After I rebooted my device, I can not receive broardcast.
Please help me, thank so much

Answer (score 7):

Starting from Android 3.0, application state was introduced.
All applications are now installed with a state set to inactive, making all it's BroadcastReceivers inactive.

To make the state as active, the user must launch the application at least once and the OS will automatically activate the app and all its BroadcastReceivers.

In your case, you need to add an activity, be it a license agreement or a help page. This will create an icon for your app for the user to click and activate the app.

Note that the application's state will be set to back inactive if the user force-closes the application.

I faced a similar problem: [Android ICS not receiving data sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992291/android-ics-not-receiving-data-sms)

I hope that solves your problem or at least put you on the right track.

regards,
Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

below Internet's uses permission

Comment: Althought I add your tag, but i can not still receive broadcast command. In android 2.2, it' ok, but android 4.0, it don't still operate.

Comment: I rebooted my device but it still don't run my broadcast.hix|T_T|

Comment: did you remove that permission tag under activity?

Comment: Once I could not get MESSAGE_RECEIVED broadcast. Then only I found if there is some other application which has receiver for same Broadcast, then sometimes our app won't get broadcast (rare scenario). I removed that messaging App then it worked for me. Check if you have anything like that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to overcome [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) security feature.

If your API level is below 12, then set the following to your intent before broadcasting it:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 32);
```

Otherwise, add the following flag to include packages which are marked as *Stopped* too:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent. FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```