# Android ICS not receiving data sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My application has a static broadcast receiver that listens to specific data sms on port 50011 to wake up the application and run.

I tested the app on a wide range of android devices (android 2.1 -> android 2.3.4) and it is working perfectly.
However, I am trying it now on Samsung Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.2 and it is failing to receive the binary sms.
The OS doesn't seem to consume that SMS as it is not showing any relevant messages in logcat.

Is anyone familiar with that issue?

Here is the receiver part that I wrote in the manifest.

```
    <receiver 
        android:name=".SmsListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:host="localhost" />
            <data android:port="50011" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: is `android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED` a part of official API?

Comment: I am sure if its part of the api, ill let u know shortly

Comment: i can't find it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

so its not part of the official api?

Comment: i think so ... thats why it can stop working in new android version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the application will not register its broadcast receivers until one of it's activities was launched by the user.

In my case the app didn't contain any Activity.

I added an activity and it is working again. :D

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

did you define `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` permission in your app `Manfest`?

Comment: yes i already added that permission and it is working on previous OS versions