# BroadcastReceiver can't receive broadcast after reboot when boot completed permission id disabled

Tags: android

In XiaoMi 2A, Android Version 4.1, I cann't receive any broadcast after reboot unless I launch my app. XiaoMi disabled boot completed broadcast for apps in default unless users open it.
I have read a lot of posts here:

[Broadcast receiver not working in ICS if the app is not started atleast once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952562/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-ics-if-the-app-is-not-started-atleast-once)

http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

[Cannot receive broadcast in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695514/cannot-receive-broadcast-in-ics?rq=1)

They all said google just made it happen after Android version 3.0. The truth is with my Galaxy Nexus of Android 4.3, the custom broadcast(not boot completed) can be received even app is not launched before after reboot.
Even with XiaoMi System, broadcast can be received after I open boot completed permission for my app. Can someone tell me why?

Here is the sending Intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.test.test");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES | intent.getFlags());
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and the receive is below:

```
  <receiver
        android:name="com.test.TestReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.test"></action>
    </intent-filter>   
  </receiver>

public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.test.test")) {
            Log.e("Chris", "received test action");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: It's just a static receiver with one action in intent filter.

Comment: there might be more issues... bro we are not wizards to tell you the solution without seeing the code :)

Comment: Your code is not for a "boot completed broadcast".

Comment: Yes, It's just my app's boot completed permission is disabled by XiaoMi system. I just want to send a custom broadcast, not boot completed broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

In Xiaomi, you can select which all apps can auto start.

```
Security App > Permissions > Autostart
```

You can allow autostart for your app here.

I think this will fix your problem